# I want to add class active to <li> tag when <a> tag under that <li> tag is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

My index.html has the following DOM structure:

```
ul -> class:nav nav-tabs -> li -> a
```

I want to add class `.active` to an `<li>` element when an `<a>` element within that `<li>` is clicked. I have written this code, but it is not working:

main.js

```
var main = function(){
    $("a").click(function() {
        $('li').removeClass('.active');
        $(this).addClass(".active"); 
    });
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: You don't need the dot in the removeClass and addClass.

Comment: Does this solve the problem for you?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var main = function(){
   $("a").click(function() {
      //travel up the DOM tree to the "closest" li element, add "active" class to it
      $(this).closest('li').addClass("active"); 
   });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

So you're close, but you have a couple of problems:

1. You want to apply the new `active` class to the containing `li`, not
   to the `a` which is getting clicked
2. [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) don't need to be prefixed with the `.`.

Comment: `$(document).ready(main);` is fine. There's no need to add another function.

Comment: this solution allows the `a` tag to be nested within another element. So this will work for ul -> class:nav nav-tabs -> li -> a  , *and* ul -> class:nav nav-tabs -> li -> div -> a )

Comment: @sixfingeredman: thanks! I've been doing it the other way for so long...and still would be if you hadn't mentioned it!

Answer (score 2):

`.name` is a **selector** for finding elements with a class of `name`. `addClass` and `removeClass` expect class names, not selectors. To add a class of "active", you simply give it the string `"active"`:

```
$(this).addClass('active')
```

You're also adding the class directly to the link which was clicked. If you want to add it to the containing `<li>`, use:

```
$(this).parent().addClass('active')
```

Answer (score 2):

You are try to manipulate `li`, but you manipulate the `a` tag.

You need to use:

```
$(this).closest('li').addClass("active");
```

**EDIT**

And also not use `.` character as others mentioned

Answer (score 0):

you need to mention class name without `.`

```
$(this).addClass("active");
```